# Websphere container stops when using stopServer.sh

Tags: docker, server, configuration, containers, websphere

Docker container automatically stops if I stop the server using the stopServer.sh script. What is recommended practice to restart the server?

I need to apply a new configuration and docker restart image_id remove the new configuration.

Comment: A container that has been stopped and not deleted can be restarted, however making this kind of changes within a container is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes I can restart it but the configuration will be removed i need only to stop start there server.some said that  by default (unless you override the CMD) the server inside the container is PID 1, so if you exit that process Docker will correctly stop the container. So you would have to start the container again, which would automatically start the server inside.

Comment: If you restart the **same container**, not a new one, you get its filesystem back.

Comment: See [Do docker containers retain file changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28574433/685806)

Comment: Yes but the configuration in server.xml will be overwrite when i do the restart

Answer (score 2):

Recommended practice is to use jython script to make any necessary configuration when the container starts. Checkout this page [ci.docker.websphere-traditional](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional) which describes all possible options, like preparing jython script or property files.

So for example your dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional:<version>
# copy property files and jython scripts, using the flag `--chown=was:root` to set the appropriate permission
RUN /work/configure.sh
```

And here is example from that page which is showing property file based config:

For example, if you had the following /work/config/001-was-config.props:

```
ResourceType=JavaVirtualMachine
ImplementingResourceType=Server
ResourceId=Cell=!{cellName}:Node=!{nodeName}:Server=!{serverName}:JavaProcessDef=:JavaVirtualMachine=
AttributeInfo=jvmEntries
#
#
#Properties
#
initialHeapSize=2048 #integer,default(0)
```

You can then create a new image which has this configuration by simply building the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional:latest
COPY --chown=was:root 001-was-config.props /work/config/
RUN /work/configure.sh
```

You may use numeric prefixes on your prop file names, so props that have dependencies can be applied in an adequate order.

It also describes best practices(quoting):

> According to Docker's best practices you should create a new image
> (FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional) which adds a single application
> and the corresponding configuration. You should avoid configuring the
> image manually (after it started) via Admin Console or wsadmin (unless
> it is for debugging purposes) because such changes won't be present if
> you spawn a new container from the image.

WebSphere traditional, not like Liberty, is using very complex configuration file structure and making manual changes to these files is not recommended.

Restarting modified container could be a temporary solution, in your local env, but it cannot be considered as recommended deployment practice.

Answer (score 0):

> What is recommended practice to restart the server?

Stop the existing container with `docker stop`, delete it with `docker rm`, then `docker run` a new container with the same options.  Using a higher-level tool like Docker Compose or Kubernetes will let you store the container options in a YAML file, which will make it easier to do this reproducibly.

> I need to apply a new configuration...the configuration in `server.xml`...

Get a copy of the default `server.xml` on your host system, maybe using `docker cp` to get it out of the existing container.  Edit it locally.  When you re-launch the container, use a Docker bind mount to inject the file into the container, like

```bash
docker run ... -v "$PWD/server.xml":/etc/websphere/server.xml ...
```

Do not use `docker exec` to try to administer the server, edit its configuration, restart it, *etc.*  Any changes you make this way will be lost as soon as the container exits, and there are circumstances that can cause it to exit outside of your direct control.